# rsync end-to-end encryption when using a VPN?

Tags: rsync, openvpn, encryption, vpn

I have a need to securely transmit data between two endpoints via rsync. This is illustrated in the diagram.

[image]

My client wants me to use a VPN connection, as the VPN server already exists and is used as a jump server to access the application environment. Plus they regard a VPN as more secure than using ssh, as the end App Server is not directly accessible from the Internet so that would be a significant change to their environment.

I understand that the rsync daemon (rsyncd) is usually used with rsync over a VPN, to avoid the performance hit double encryption (VPN and ssh) would involve; there is a large amount of data to transmit and only a weekend to do it in so this is a real concern.

However I have also been asked to ensure that the transmission is encrypted end-to-end, even between the VPN server and the receiving node, which is something that I believe only ssh, not rsh or rsyncd could provide?

Using the VPN server as a staging server is not an option either.

So, am I stuck with VPN + ssh here as a solution, or is there something I'm missing that could help?

Both the VPN server and App Server are in AWS if that makes any difference?

Comment: It's impossible to use the VPN (it does its own encryption) as the transport, have your end-to-end encryption on top of it **and** avoid incurring in encrypting the traffic twice. Somebody is going to have to drop one of the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to avoid something between the VPN endpoint and the far end sniffing your `rsync`, then yes you need to wrap it in another layer terminated only by the far end. SSH is one option for that; stunnel might be another if you have enough control over the process.